# New vector with letters representing unique combinations of other vectors

Tags: r, aggregate

I have

```
dat <-data.frame(study=letters[c(1,1,1,4,4,4,4,10,10)],n1i=c(25,25,22,38,50,30,30,50,50))
```

I want

```
     study n1i grp
1     a  25   A
2     a  25   A
3     a  22   B
4     d  38   A
5     d  50   B
6     d  30   C
7     d  30   C
8     j  50   A
9     j  50   A
```

But this...

```
dat$grp<-  
  as.vector(unlist(aggregate(dat$n1i,
   list(dat$study), function(x) LETTERS[1:length(x)])$x))
```

...gives me

```
> dat
  study n1i grp
1     a  25   A
2     a  25   B
3     a  22   C
4     d  38   A
5     d  50   B
6     d  30   C
7     d  30   D
8     j  50   A
9     j  50   B
```

In words I want the "grp" letters to go from 1 to whenever it reaches the last unique combination of study*n1i.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dat <-data.frame(study=letters[c(1,1,1,4,4,4,4,10,10)],n1i=c(25,25,22,38,50,30,30,50,50)) 

library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  group_by(study) %>%                    # for each study
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%          # get the number of row as an id
  group_by(study, n1i) %>%               # for each study and n1i combination
  transmute(grp = LETTERS[min(id)]) %>%  # add the letters based on the minimum id value of that combination, while removing the id column
  ungroup()                              # forget the grouping

# # A tibble: 9 x 3
#   study   n1i grp  
#   <fct> <dbl> <chr>
# 1 a        25 A    
# 2 a        25 A    
# 3 a        22 C    
# 4 d        38 A    
# 5 d        50 B    
# 6 d        30 C    
# 7 d        30 C    
# 8 j        50 A    
# 9 j        50 A
```

This approach assumes that the duplicated rows are one after the other.

Comment: this is not correct. if study and n1i columns are the same, the grp letter should be the same

Comment: This doesn't return the desired output (row 3)

Answer (score 4):

This is based on run length incoding ID, which assumes that unique combination only appear in chunks and not in separated rows.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  group_by(study) %>%
  mutate(grp =rleid(n1i)) %>%
  mutate(grp = LETTERS[grp]) %>%
  ungroup()
dat2
# # A tibble: 9 x 3
#   study   n1i grp  
#   <fct> <dbl> <chr>
# 1 a        25 A    
# 2 a        25 A    
# 3 a        22 B    
# 4 d        38 A    
# 5 d        50 B    
# 6 d        30 C    
# 7 d        30 C    
# 8 j        50 A    
# 9 j        50 A
```

This solution may not be perfect. For example, if the data frame looks like this:

```
study   n1i
   a     25
   a     22
   a     25
```

The run length encoding would become `1, 2, 3`. In this case, you may want to order your data frame first to make the same row in the same chunk. I did not put an order or arrange call in my solution because I do not know if reorder the rows is what you want.

**UPDATE**

AntoniosK commented that the first three rows should be `A, A, C`. I have added `min_rank` to the pipe operation to account for this statement.

```
dat2 <- dat %>%
  group_by(study) %>%
  mutate(grp =rleid(n1i)) %>%
  mutate(grp = min_rank(grp)) %>%
  mutate(grp = LETTERS[grp]) %>%
  ungroup()
dat2
# # A tibble: 9 x 3
#   study   n1i grp  
#   <fct> <dbl> <chr>
# 1 a        25 A    
# 2 a        25 A    
# 3 a        22 C    
# 4 d        38 A    
# 5 d        50 B    
# 6 d        30 C    
# 7 d        30 C    
# 8 j        50 A    
# 9 j        50 A
```

Comment: Which could be ensured with dat[with(dat, order(study,n1i)),]

Comment: @Anomie If you can reorder your dataframe, and then my solution would work. Otherwise, I think sotos' solution is better, which does not consider the order of row.

Comment: @AntoniosK Thanks for your comment. I have updated my post.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a one liner with no additional packages,

```
LETTERS[with(dat, ave(n1i, study, FUN = function(i) 
                                cumsum(!duplicated(i) | duplicated(i, fromLast = TRUE))))]
#[1] "A" "A" "B" "A" "B" "C" "C" "A" "A"
```

Comment: The first 3 values of the new column (i.e. for study = a) should be A, A, C and not A, A, B.

Answer (score 3):

Or another option is `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, grp := LETTERS[rleid(n1i)], study]
dat
#   study n1i grp
#1:     a  25   A
#2:     a  25   A
#3:     a  22   B
#4:     d  38   A
#5:     d  50   B
#6:     d  30   C
#7:     d  30   C
#8:     j  50   A
#9:     j  50   A
```

### EDIT

Based on @AntoniosK's comment, the correct output should be

```
setDT(dat)[, i1 := seq_len(.N), study][, grp := LETTERS[min(i1)], 
                .(study, n1i)][, i1 := NULL][]
#   study n1i grp
#1:     a  25   A
#2:     a  25   A
#3:     a  22   C
#4:     d  38   A
#5:     d  50   B
#6:     d  30   C
#7:     d  30   C
#8:     j  50   A
#9:     j  50   A
```

Answer (score 0):

With `tidyverse`, using `dplyr::group_indices` :

```
dat %>%
  split(.$study) %>%
  map_dfr(~mutate(.,id = LETTERS[
    group_indices(.,factor(n1i,unique(n1i)))]))

#   study n1i id
# 1     a  25  A
# 2     a  25  A
# 3     a  22  B
# 4     d  38  A
# 5     d  50  B
# 6     d  30  C
# 7     d  30  C
# 8     j  50  A
# 9     j  50  A
```